# jQuery .load() then loop and .find() not working?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem about this:

I have two page are **index.html** and **page.html**

In **page.html**, I have a code:

```
<a class="abc" href="111">xxx</a>
<a class="abc" href="222">xxx</a>
<a class="abc" href="333">xxx</a>
```

In **index.html**, I have a code:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<a onclick="getmany()">GET MANY</a>

<div id="load"></div>

<script language="javascript">
function getmany(){
    $('#load').load('/page.html body',function(data){
        count = $(data).find('.abc').length;
        for(i=0;i<count;i++){
            data = $(data).find('.abc:eq('+i+')').attr('href');
            $('#result').append(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

When I click **GET MENY**, the **div#result** only display **111**

But I want it display **111222333**

Can I help me? Thankyou so much!!! <3

Comment: Yes bro. I want display all of them. Please help me. Tks <3

Comment: Try more like -> https://jsfiddle.net/vrdqzod2/

Comment: I change .attr() to .html() but it only display first matching? :-O

Comment: OMG. You are so pretty. Thankyou so much! How can I vote you bro? <3

Comment: I'll post it so you can accept it as solved

Answer (score 0):

To display all the attributes, iterate over the elements and append each one

```
function getmany(){
    $('#load').load('/page.html body', function(data){
        $(data).find('.abc').each(function(index, element) {
            $('#result').append( $(element).attr('href') );
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What happen???
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Bro. Why i try with 
`for(i=0;i<count;i++){
            alert(i);
}`
it will alert three times, but when I using .find().attr() it only display first matching? Why? :-O

Comment: It's probably because `$(data).find('.abc:eq('+i+')')` fails. You're overwriting `data` on each iteration, so it only works the first time, as the second time you loop `data` is something else, not the elements.

Comment: Lesson:  Always declare variables with `var`, `let` or `const`, don't do what you've done, and make them global. Secondly, use different names for your variables.